# Firebug: "event is not defined"

Tags: javascript, events

I have a constructor with these methods:

```
    
function getMouseXY(event){
        var x = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = event.clientY - this.offsetTop;
    return [x,y];
}

function alertx(){
    var c = this.getMouseXY(event);
    alert(c[0]);
}
```

In the HTML code i assign the alertx function to a HTML5 canvas' event mouseup:

```
document.getElementById('cbackground').addEventListener('mouseup', object.alertx, false);
```

What's the expected result? That clicking on the canvas it shows the X position of the mouse, instead i get nothing. Further exploration with Firebug gets me the error "event is not defined". I don't know how to avoid that! Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see a couple of issues:

1. The `alertx()` doesn't receive an `event` argument.
2. In that function you are calling `getMouseXY` using `this`. The this keywords at that moment, will refer to the element that triggered the event.
3. You are binding the event handler to an unknown `object` variable.

I think you want to do something like this:

```
function getMouseXY(event){
        var x = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft, // notice, 'this' is used
            y = event.clientY - this.offsetTop;

    return [x,y];
}

function alertx(event){
    var c = getMouseXY.call(this, event); // set the element as 'this'
    alert(c[0]);
}
```

And if you have a constructor function, and the above functions are instance methods, you can do something like this:

```
function MyObject () {  // constructor
}

MyObject.prototype.getMouseXY = function (event) {
        var x = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft,
            y = event.clientY - this.offsetTop;

    return [x,y];
};

MyObject.prototype.alertx = function (event, element) {
    var c = this.getMouseXY.call(element, event); 
    alert(c[0]);
}
```

When binding the event, you can add an anonymous function, to enforce the context:

```
var object = new MyObject();
document.getElementById('cbackground').addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
  object.alertx(e, this); // alertx will be called with the correct 'this'
}, false);
```

---

**Edit:**  In response to your comment, you just have to know how the context (the `this` keyword) is set **implicitly**:

When you call a instance method like:

```
obj.method();
```

The `this` keyword inside the `method`, will refer to `obj`.

The same thing happens when you call global variables, since they are members of the global object (`window` in browser scripting):

```
globalFunction();
```

Is equivalent to:

```
window.globalFunction();
```

And the context inside that function will be the global object itself (`window`).

Another case happens when you use the `new` operator:

```
var instance = new MyConstructor();
```

The `this` keyword in that case will be a *new object,* created by the use of the `new` operator.

When you use a function as an event handler, the `this` keyword will refer to the element tha triggered the event:

```
document.getElementById('myId').onclick = obj.myFunction;
```

In that case `myFunction` is a instance method of `obj`, but the `this` keyword will refer to the DOM element that has been clicked.

And finally, as you saw in my code, the context can be set **explicitly** by the use of [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Comment: Amazing man, thanks! The .call solved the problem. I'll read more about it. I DO have a constructor, and those functions are methods of it, what's the advantage of prototyping in this case?

Comment: Humm. I modified the code to make it compliant to the prototyping model (constructor, add method by prototyping them, your second case) and i'm getting a "this.getmouseXY is undefined".

Comment: Did you see anything odd CMS?

Answer (score 0):

On `var c = this.getMouseXY(event);` you are passing an unassigned variable (event) to the function, which is why it is blowing up.  Maybe you forgot to add in the argument to alertx()?

Comment: I just used event to make the clientY and clientX functions to work, not because i wanted so... :( Don't know how to handle it inside alertx.

Answer (score 0):

In function alertx event is never initialized.

If you use `function alertx(event)` it should work.